# CMake failing to link Boost regex library in Clion

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, ld, clion

I am trying to get Boost 1.72 release ready to use in my C++ project. OS is Windows 10. I use Clion as an IDE and CMake 3.17 and gcc 8.1.0 as toolchain. I tried to follow lots of different instruction on the web trying to "install" Boost properly, and I ended up with these steps (all italic folders names are valid full-qualified paths):

1. Unpack Boost source code, go to *boost-sources-dir*/tools/build, run bootstrap.bat gcc
2. Then run b2 install --prefix="*provided-boost-build-folder*"
3. Then add *provided-boost-build-folder*/bin to PATH variable.
4. Go back to *boost-sources-dir* and run b2 --build-dir="*boost-sources-dir*\build" --prefix="*boost-install-dir*" toolset=gcc install --build-type=complete -j 4
5. Now I have "include" and "lib" folders in *boost-install-dir*. I open Clion and add parameters for CMake in Clion settings:

```
-DBOOST_INCLUDEDIR="boost-install-dir\include" 
-DBOOST_LIBRARYDIR="boost-install-dir\lib" 
-DBOOST_ROOT="boost-install-dir"
```

And my CMakeLists.txt is below:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(DBMSProject)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "--coverage")

find_package(Boost)
# I also tried to use the line below instead of a line above, but it gave me a strange error
# "Could NOT find Boost (missing: regex) (found version "1.72.0")"
# find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS regex)

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(DBMSProject main.cpp /* some other stuff */)
target_link_libraries(DBMSProject -static)
#target_link_libraries(DBMSProject ${Boost_LIBRARIES})  # that didn't work
target_link_libraries(DBMSProject Boost::boost ${Boost_REGEX_LIBRARY})  # neither that does
```

Just some sample code in main.cpp to see if compiling and linking work:

```
/* Other headers */
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
. . .

int main() {
    std::string line;
    boost::regex pat( "^Subject: (Re: |Aw: )*(.*)" );

    while (std::cin)
    {
        std::getline(std::cin, line);
        boost::smatch matches;
        if (boost::regex_match(line, matches, pat))
            std::cout << matches[2] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

After trying to run this program, it gives lots of link errors:

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable DBMSProject.exe
CMakeFiles\DBMSProject.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `boost::re_detail_107200::cpp_regex_traits_char_layer<char>::cpp_regex_traits_char_layer(boost::re_detail_107200::cpp_regex_traits_base<char> const&)':
C:/Users/Documents/Programs/boost/include/boost-1_72/boost/regex/v4/cpp_regex_traits.hpp:370: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_107200::cpp_regex_traits_char_layer<char>::init()'
CMakeFiles\DBMSProject.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `boost::re_detail_107200::raw_storage::extend(unsigned long long)':
C:/Users/Documents/Programs/boost/include/boost-1_72/boost/regex/v4/regex_raw_buffer.hpp:131: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_107200::raw_storage::resize(unsigned long long)'
CMakeFiles\DBMSProject.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `boost::re_detail_107200::save_state_init::save_state_init(boost::re_detail_107200::saved_state**, boost::re_detail_107200::saved_state**)':
C:/Users//Douments/Programs/boost/include/boost-1_72/boost/regex/v4/perl_matcher_non_recursive.hpp:110: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_107200::get_mem_block()'
CMakeFiles\DBMSProject.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `boost::re_detail_107200::save_state_init::~save_state_init()':
C:/Users/Documents/Programs/boost/include/boost-1_72/boost/regex/v4/perl_matcher_non_recursive.hpp:118: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_107200::put_mem_block(void*)'
CMakeFiles\DBMSProject.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `boost::re_detail_107200::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::match_imp()':
C:/Users//ocuments/Programs/boost/include/boost-1_72/boost/regex/v4/perl_matcher_common.hpp:221: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_107200::verify_options(unsigned int, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)'
CMakeFiles\DBMSProject.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `boost::re_detail_107200::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::unwind_extra_block(bool)':
C:/Users/Documents/Programs/boost/include/boost-1_72/boost/regex/v4/perl_matcher_non_recursive.hpp:1371: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_107200::put_mem_block(void*)'
CMakeFiles\DBMSProject.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `void boost::re_detail_107200::raise_error<boost::regex_traits_wrapper<boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > >(boost::regex_traits_wrapper<boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::error_type)':
C:/Users/Documents/Programs/boost/include/boost-1_72/boost/regex/pattern_except.hpp:75: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_107200::raise_runtime_error(std::runtime_error const&)'
CMakeFiles\DBMSProject.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `boost::re_detail_107200::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::extend_stack()':
C:/Users/Documents/Programs/boost/include/boost-1_72/boost/regex/v4/perl_matcher_non_recursive.hpp:236: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_107200::get_mem_block()'
CMakeFiles\DBMSProject.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `boost::re_detail_107200::basic_regex_parser<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::fail(boost::regex_constants::error_type, long long, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, long long)':
C:/Users/Documents/Programs/boost/include/boost-1_72/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_parser.hpp:241: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::regex_error(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, boost::regex_constants::error_type, long long)'
C:/Users/Documents/Programs/boost/include/boost-1_72/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_parser.hpp:242: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::raise() const'
C:/Users//Douments/Programs/boost/include/boost-1_72/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_parser.hpp:241: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::~regex_error()'
C:/Users//v4/basic_regex_parser.hpp:241: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::~regex_error()'
CMakeFiles\DBMSProject.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `boost::re_dtail_107200::basic_regex_creator<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::fixup_recursions(boost::re_detail_107200::re_syntax_base*)':
C:/Users//Documents/Programs/boost/include/boost-1_72/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:785: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::regex_error(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, boost::regex_constants::error_type, long long)'
C:/Users//v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:785: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::~regex_error()'
C:/Users//Documents/Programs/boost/include/boost-1_72/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:874: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::regex_error(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, boost::regex_constants::error_type, long long)'
C:/Users//Documents/Programs/boost/include/boost-1_72/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:875: undefined reference to `boost::/Documents/Programs/boost/include/boost-1_72/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:874: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::~regex_error()'
C:/Users//Documents/Programs/boost/include/boost-1_72/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:785: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::~regex_error()'
C:/Users//Documents/Programs/boost/include/boost-1_72/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:874: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::~regex_error()'
CMakeFiles\DBMSProject.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `boost::re_detail_107200::basic_regex_creator<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::create_startmaps(boost::re_detail_107200::re_syntax_base*)':
C:/Users//Documents/Programs/boost/include/boost-1_72/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:940: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::regex_error(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, boost::regex_constants::error_type, long long)'
C:/Users//Documents/Programs/boost/include/boost-1_72/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:941: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::raise() const'
C:/Users//Documents/Programs/boost/include/boost-1_72/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:940: undefined reference to `boost::re
```

But I can clearly see with my eyes the definitions of "absent" symbols in the same .hpp file as where the errors are! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens when you use `find_package(Boost CONFIG REQUIRED COMPONENTS regex)`? With the latest CMake and Boost versions, it is cleanest to use `CONFIG` mode to find Boost, and use the imported Boost targets `Boost::regex`.

Comment: @squareskittles, another error.

"Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Boost" with any of
  the following names:

    BoostConfig.cmake
    boost-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Boost" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Boost_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Boost"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed."

Comment: Also tried to use target_link_libraries() command as follows:
target_link_libraries(DBMSProject -static -Lboost-install-dir\\lib\\libboost_regex-mgw81-mt-d-x64-1_72.dll)
But if gave me the same linkage error.

Comment: Yes, you should set the variable `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` in your CMake, to point to the location where `b2` built the Boost libraries. There should be a BoostConfig.cmake file there.

Comment: @squareskittles it's much better now (I start to understand things), I found that my boost-install-dir actually contains all CMake configs for Boost, but CMake is continuing to complain:
Found package configuration file:

    boost-install-dir/lib/cmake/boost_regex-1.72.0/boost_regex-config.cmake

  but it set boost_regex_FOUND to FALSE so package "boost_regex" is
  considered to be NOT FOUND.  Reason given by package: //

  No suitable build variant has been found. //

Comment: @squareskittles 
  The following variants have been tried and rejected: //

  * libboost_regex-mgw81-mt-d-x64-1_72.dll.a (mgw81, detected mgw8, set
  Boost_COMPILER to override)

so, how is it possible if I used the same compiler (gcc, I guess) all the time?

Comment: @squareskittles so, I found it might be a bug https://github.com/boostorg/boost_install/issues/33 and I try to use Boost_COMPILER option as a workaround for now.

Comment: Ok, it sounds like there is a *difference* between the Boost libraries you built, and the compiler/build settings you are using with CMake. I.e. Compiler type mismatch, GCC version mismatch, static vs shared libraries, 32-bit vs 64-bit, etc.

Comment: And yes, perhaps, it is a bug! :)

Comment: @squareskittles thank you for your help, I really appreciate it! It's working now :)

Comment: Glad it's working! Please consider writing up an answer post showing the CMake code you got working so future visitors can learn from it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to work. My CMakeLists.txt now looks as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(DBMSProject)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "--coverage")
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${BOOST_LIBRARYDIR}\\cmake)

find_package(Boost CONFIG REQUIRED COMPONENTS regex)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(DBMSProject main.cpp /* stuff */)
target_link_libraries(DBMSProject -static)
#target_link_libraries(DBMSProject ${Boost_LIBRARIES}) # haven't tried that but I think it might work as well
target_link_libraries(DBMSProject Boost::regex)
```

It also turned out that I don't need -DBOOST... parameters for CMake if I don't use them in CMakeLists.txt, so I excluded -DBOOST_INCLUDEDIR and -DBOOST_ROOT from them.